# Simplifying Long Lines Of Codes

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a program that calculates the monthly electricity bill based on usage. The codes are not neat and does not look very...concise, but it works. I tried using an array (have not learned that in my course yet) because when I searched around for answers, arrays will usually be the solution to it. However, when I use it in my code, it only calculates for the second statement, like if I have `If...Else If`, it'll only check for `Else If` and ignore the initial `If`.

I have created another project to resemble the problem. As you'll see below, the month is only until May, and I have to get it to October...

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       
        Dim marTA, aprTA, mayTA As Single

        Dim mar, apr, may As Decimal

        Decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, mar) : Decimal.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, apr)
        Decimal.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, may)

        Select Case True
            Case mar = 0
                marTA = 3D + (3D * 0.06)
                TextBox4.Text = marTA.ToString("C2").Replace("$", "RM ")
            Case mar >= 1 And mar < 201
                marTA = CSng(mar * 0.109)
                TextBox4.Text = marTA.ToString("C2").Replace("$", "RM ")
            Case mar >= 201 And mar < 301
                marTA = CSng((200 * 0.109) + ((mar - 200) * 0.153))
                TextBox4.Text = marTA.ToString("C2").Replace("$", "RM ")
            Case mar >= 301 And mar < 601
                marTA = CSng((200 * 0.109) + (100 * 0.153) + ((mar - 300) * 0.172))
                TextBox4.Text = marTA.ToString("C2").Replace("$", "RM ")
            Case mar >= 601 And mar < 901
                marTA = CSng((200 * 0.109) + (100 * 0.153) + (300 * 0.172) + ((mar - 600) * 0.182))
                TextBox4.Text = marTA.ToString("C2").Replace("$", "RM ")
            Case mar >= 901
                marTA = CSng((200 * 0.109) + (100 * 0.153) + (300 * 0.172) + (300 * 0.182) + ((mar - 900) * 0.215))
                TextBox4.Text = marTA.ToString("C2").Replace("$", "RM ")
        End Select

        Select Case True
            Case apr = 0
                aprTA = 3 + (3 * 0.06)
                TextBox4.Text = aprTA.ToString("C2").Replace("$", "RM ")
            Case apr >= 1 And apr < 201
                aprTA = CSng(apr * 0.109)
                TextBox4.Text = aprTA.ToString("C2").Replace("$", "RM ")
            Case apr >= 201 And apr < 301
                aprTA = CSng((200 * 0.109) + ((apr - 200) * 0.153))
                TextBox4.Text = aprTA.ToString("C2").Replace("$", "RM ")
            Case apr >= 301 And apr < 601
                aprTA = CSng((200 * 0.109) + (100 * 0.153) + ((apr - 300) * 0.172))
                TextBox4.Text = aprTA.ToString("C2").Replace("$", "RM ")
            Case apr >= 601 And apr < 901
                aprTA = CSng((200 * 0.109) + (100 * 0.153) + (300 * 0.172) + ((apr - 600) * 0.182))
                TextBox4.Text = aprTA.ToString("C2").Replace("$", "RM ")
            Case apr >= 901
                aprTA = CSng((200 * 0.109) + (100 * 0.153) + (300 * 0.172) + (300 * 0.182) + ((apr - 900) * 0.215))
                TextBox4.Text = aprTA.ToString("C2").Replace("$", "RM ")
        End Select

        Select Case True
            Case may = 0
                mayTA = 3 + (3 * 0.06)
                TextBox4.Text = mayTA.ToString("C2").Replace("$", "RM ")
            Case may >= 1 And may < 201
                mayTA = CSng(may * 0.109)
                TextBox4.Text = mayTA.ToString("C2").Replace("$", "RM ")
            Case may >= 201 And may < 301
                mayTA = CSng((200 * 0.109) + ((may - 200) * 0.153))
                TextBox4.Text = mayTA.ToString("C2").Replace("$", "RM ")
            Case may >= 301 And may < 601
                mayTA = CSng((200 * 0.109) + (100 * 0.153) + ((may - 300) * 0.172))
                TextBox4.Text = mayTA.ToString("C2").Replace("$", "RM ")
            Case may >= 601 And may < 901
                mayTA = CSng((200 * 0.109) + (100 * 0.153) + (300 * 0.172) + ((may - 600) * 0.182))
                TextBox4.Text = mayTA.ToString("C2").Replace("$", "RM ")
            Case may >= 901
                mayTA = CSng((200 * 0.109) + (100 * 0.153) + (300 * 0.172) + (300 * 0.182) + ((may - 900) * 0.215))
                TextBox4.Text = mayTA.ToString("C2").Replace("$", "RM ")
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

Design View:

[image: Design View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an acronym in programming, DRY. It stands for Don't Repeat Yourself. A few reasons for this are...

1. Easier to debug.
2. Easier to change - just one spot instead of several.
3. Easier to read and understand.
4. Less error prone. If you try to write the same code several times you will make a mistake in the rewriting.

There are several ways to achieve DRY. One is to move repetative code to a separate function. See `GetUsageCharge` for a example of this.

Another way is to create a collection of like objects. Then use a loop to apply the repetitive code to each item in the collection. See `TextBoxes` and the `For Each`.

```
Private Function GetUsageCharge(usage As Integer) As Decimal
    Select Case usage
        Case 0
            Return CDec(3 + (3 * 0.06))
        Case 1 To 200
            Return CDec(usage * 0.109)
        Case 201 To 300
            Return CDec((200 * 0.109) + ((usage - 200) * 0.153))
        Case 301 To 600
            Return CDec((200 * 0.109) + (100 * 0.153) + ((usage - 300) * 0.172))
        Case 601 To 900
            Return CDec((200 * 0.109) + (100 * 0.153) + (300 * 0.172) + ((usage - 600) * 0.182))
        Case >= 901
            Return CDec((200 * 0.109) + (100 * 0.153) + (300 * 0.172) + (300 * 0.182) + ((usage - 900) * 0.215))
    End Select
    Return 0
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim TotalCost As Decimal
    Dim usage As Integer
    Dim TextBoxes As New List(Of TextBox) From {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3}
    For Each tb In TextBoxes
        If Integer.TryParse(tb.Text, usage) Then
            TotalCost += GetUsageCharge(usage)
        End If
    Next
    TextBox4.Text = TotalCost.ToString("C2").Replace("$", "RM ")
End Sub
```

As you can see this code is much simpler, fewer variables etc.

Note: You can get rid of `.Replace("$", "RM ")` if you add...

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("ms-MY")
```

in the `Form.Load`

Comment: This works wonder! However, there's a bug - the amount of total cost will increase continuously if the user keeps clicking on the button, hence the my messy codes. It's also why I separate them to avoid this issue, but that's for another question and this can be sorted out. Thank you @Mary

Comment: TotalCost is a local variable that start as 0 each time the button is clicked.

Comment: Oh my god, I am dumb..I declare it as `Public` because I have another groupbox to sum the total cost for each month, and also to add them into a ListBox to print a receipt. I am sorry, my fault.